# How can I unescape HTML character entities in Java?

Tags: java, html, string, eclipse, decode

Basically, I would like to decode a given HTML document, and replace all special characters, such as `"&nbsp;"` → `" "` and `"&gt;"` → `">"`.

In [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework), we can make use of the [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode) method.

What's the equivalent function in Java?

Comment: &nbsp; is called character entity. Edited the title.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

I have used the Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4-java.lang.String-) for this:

> Unescapes a string containing entity
>   escapes to a string containing the
>   actual Unicode characters
>   corresponding to the escapes. Supports
>   HTML 4.0 entities.

Comment: Sadly I just realized today that it does not decode HTMLspecial characters very well :(

Comment: a dirty trick is to store the value initially in a hidden field to escape it, then the target field should get the value from the hidden field.

Comment: Class StringEscapeUtils is deprecated and moved to [Apache commons-text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/)

Comment: I want to convert the string `<p>&uuml;&egrave;</p>` to `<p>üé</p>`, with `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()` I get `&lt;p&gt;üè&lt;/p&gt;`. Is there a way to keep existing html tags intact?

Comment: If I have something like `&#147;` which escapes to a quotation mark in Windows-1252 but some control character in Unicode, can the escaping encoding be changed?

Comment: The link is half-broken (page anchor).

Answer (score 69):

The libraries mentioned in other answers would be fine solutions, but if you already happen to be digging through real-world HTML content in your project, the [`Jsoup`](http://jsoup.org) project has a lot more to offer than just managing *"ampersand pound FFFF semicolon"* things.

```
// textValue: <p>This is a&nbsp;sample. \"Granny\" Smith &#8211;.<\/p>\r\n
// becomes this: This is a sample. "Granny" Smith –.
// with one line of code:
// Jsoup.parse(textValue).getText(); // for older versions of Jsoup
Jsoup.parse(textValue).text();

// Another possibility may be the static unescapeEntities method:
boolean strictMode = true;
String unescapedString = org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(textValue, strictMode);
```

And you also get the convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)-like methods.  It's open source and [MIT License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License).

Comment: upvote+, but I should point that newer versions of Jsoup use `.text()` instead of `.getText()`

Comment: Perhaps more direct is to use `org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(String string, boolean inAttribute)`. API docs: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#unescapeEntities-java.lang.String-boolean-

Comment: This was perfect, since I'm already using Jsoup in my project. Also, @danneu was right - Parser.unescapeEntities works exactly as advertised.

Comment: why then does the following not return un-escaped html: Parser.unescapeEntities(Jsoup.parse("<div>&#8226;</div>").text(), true)

Comment: @DavesPlanet, what happens when you try `Parser.unescapeEntities("<div>&#8226;</div>", true)`

Comment: @Dale see question 77405300 for details but what happens is I get a utf16 string with a bullet point out instead of the text

Answer (score 46):

I tried [Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons)' [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml3-java.lang.String-) in my project, but I wasn't satisfied with its performance. It turns out, it does a lot of unnecessary operations. For one, it allocates a StringWriter for every call, even if there's nothing to unescape in the string.  I've rewritten that code differently, and now it works much faster.

The following code unescapes all [HTML 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#HTML_3) symbols and numeric escapes (equivalent to Apache *unescapeHtml3*). You can just add more entries to the map if you need [HTML 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#HTML_4).

```
package com.example;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class StringUtils {

    public static final String unescapeHtml3(final String input) {
        StringWriter writer = null;
        int len = input.length();
        int i = 1;
        int st = 0;
        while (true) {
            // Look for '&'
            while (i < len && input.charAt(i-1) != '&')
                i++;
            if (i >= len)
                break;

            // Found '&', look for ';'
            int j = i;
            while (j < len && j < i + MAX_ESCAPE + 1 && input.charAt(j) != ';')
                j++;
            if (j == len || j < i + MIN_ESCAPE || j == i + MAX_ESCAPE + 1) {
                i++;
                continue;
            }

            // Found escape
            if (input.charAt(i) == '#') {
                // Numeric escape
                int k = i + 1;
                int radix = 10;

                final char firstChar = input.charAt(k);
                if (firstChar == 'x' || firstChar == 'X') {
                    k++;
                    radix = 16;
                }

                try {
                    int entityValue = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(k, j), radix);

                    if (writer == null)
                        writer = new StringWriter(input.length());
                    writer.append(input.substring(st, i - 1));

                    if (entityValue > 0xFFFF) {
                        final char[] chrs = Character.toChars(entityValue);
                        writer.write(chrs[0]);
                        writer.write(chrs[1]);
                    } else {
                        writer.write(entityValue);
                    }

                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else {
                // Named escape
                CharSequence value = lookupMap.get(input.substring(i, j));
                if (value == null) {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (writer == null)
                    writer = new StringWriter(input.length());
                writer.append(input.substring(st, i - 1));

                writer.append(value);
            }

            // Skip escape
            st = j + 1;
            i = st;
        }

        if (writer != null) {
            writer.append(input.substring(st, len));
            return writer.toString();
        }
        return input;
    }

    private static final String[][] ESCAPES = {
        {"\"",     "quot"}, // " - double-quote
        {"&",      "amp"}, // & - ampersand
        {"<",      "lt"}, // < - less-than
        {">",      "gt"}, // > - greater-than

        // Mapping to escape ISO-8859-1 characters to their named HTML 3.x equivalents.
        {"\u00A0", "nbsp"},   // Non-breaking space
        {"\u00A1", "iexcl"},  // Inverted exclamation mark
        {"\u00A2", "cent"},   // Cent sign
        {"\u00A3", "pound"},  // Pound sign
        {"\u00A4", "curren"}, // Currency sign
        {"\u00A5", "yen"},    // Yen sign = yuan sign
        {"\u00A6", "brvbar"}, // Broken bar = broken vertical bar
        {"\u00A7", "sect"},   // Section sign
        {"\u00A8", "uml"},    // Diaeresis = spacing diaeresis
        {"\u00A9", "copy"},   // © - copyright sign
        {"\u00AA", "ordf"},   // Feminine ordinal indicator
        {"\u00AB", "laquo"},  // Left-pointing double angle quotation mark = left pointing guillemet
        {"\u00AC", "not"},    // Not sign
        {"\u00AD", "shy"},    // Soft hyphen = discretionary hyphen
        {"\u00AE", "reg"},    // ® - registered trademark sign
        {"\u00AF", "macr"},   // Macron = spacing macron = overline = APL overbar
        {"\u00B0", "deg"},    // Degree sign
        {"\u00B1", "plusmn"}, // Plus-minus sign = plus-or-minus sign
        {"\u00B2", "sup2"},   // Superscript two = superscript digit two = squared
        {"\u00B3", "sup3"},   // Superscript three = superscript digit three = cubed
        {"\u00B4", "acute"},  // Acute accent = spacing acute
        {"\u00B5", "micro"},  // Micro sign
        {"\u00B6", "para"},   // Pilcrow sign = paragraph sign
        {"\u00B7", "middot"}, // Middle dot = Georgian comma = Greek middle dot
        {"\u00B8", "cedil"},  // Cedilla = spacing cedilla
        {"\u00B9", "sup1"},   // Superscript one = superscript digit one
        {"\u00BA", "ordm"},   // Masculine ordinal indicator
        {"\u00BB", "raquo"},  // Right-pointing double angle quotation mark = right pointing guillemet
        {"\u00BC", "frac14"}, // Vulgar fraction one quarter = fraction one quarter
        {"\u00BD", "frac12"}, // Vulgar fraction one half = fraction one half
        {"\u00BE", "frac34"}, // Vulgar fraction three quarters = fraction three quarters
        {"\u00BF", "iquest"}, // Inverted question mark = turned question mark
        {"\u00C0", "Agrave"}, // А - uppercase A, grave accent
        {"\u00C1", "Aacute"}, // Б - uppercase A, acute accent
        {"\u00C2", "Acirc"},  // В - uppercase A, circumflex accent
        {"\u00C3", "Atilde"}, // Г - uppercase A, tilde
        {"\u00C4", "Auml"},   // Д - uppercase A, umlaut
        {"\u00C5", "Aring"},  // Е - uppercase A, ring
        {"\u00C6", "AElig"},  // Ж - uppercase AE
        {"\u00C7", "Ccedil"}, // З - uppercase C, cedilla
        {"\u00C8", "Egrave"}, // И - uppercase E, grave accent
        {"\u00C9", "Eacute"}, // Й - uppercase E, acute accent
        {"\u00CA", "Ecirc"},  // К - uppercase E, circumflex accent
        {"\u00CB", "Euml"},   // Л - uppercase E, umlaut
        {"\u00CC", "Igrave"}, // М - uppercase I, grave accent
        {"\u00CD", "Iacute"}, // Н - uppercase I, acute accent
        {"\u00CE", "Icirc"},  // О - uppercase I, circumflex accent
        {"\u00CF", "Iuml"},   // П - uppercase I, umlaut
        {"\u00D0", "ETH"},    // Р - uppercase Eth, Icelandic
        {"\u00D1", "Ntilde"}, // С - uppercase N, tilde
        {"\u00D2", "Ograve"}, // Т - uppercase O, grave accent
        {"\u00D3", "Oacute"}, // У - uppercase O, acute accent
        {"\u00D4", "Ocirc"},  // Ф - uppercase O, circumflex accent
        {"\u00D5", "Otilde"}, // Х - uppercase O, tilde
        {"\u00D6", "Ouml"},   // Ц - uppercase O, umlaut
        {"\u00D7", "times"},  // Multiplication sign
        {"\u00D8", "Oslash"}, // Ш - uppercase O, slash
        {"\u00D9", "Ugrave"}, // Щ - uppercase U, grave accent
        {"\u00DA", "Uacute"}, // Ъ - uppercase U, acute accent
        {"\u00DB", "Ucirc"},  // Ы - uppercase U, circumflex accent
        {"\u00DC", "Uuml"},   // Ь - uppercase U, umlaut
        {"\u00DD", "Yacute"}, // Э - uppercase Y, acute accent
        {"\u00DE", "THORN"},  // Ю - uppercase THORN, Icelandic
        {"\u00DF", "szlig"},  // Я - lowercase sharps, German
        {"\u00E0", "agrave"}, // а - lowercase a, grave accent
        {"\u00E1", "aacute"}, // б - lowercase a, acute accent
        {"\u00E2", "acirc"},  // в - lowercase a, circumflex accent
        {"\u00E3", "atilde"}, // г - lowercase a, tilde
        {"\u00E4", "auml"},   // д - lowercase a, umlaut
        {"\u00E5", "aring"},  // е - lowercase a, ring
        {"\u00E6", "aelig"},  // ж - lowercase ae
        {"\u00E7", "ccedil"}, // з - lowercase c, cedilla
        {"\u00E8", "egrave"}, // и - lowercase e, grave accent
        {"\u00E9", "eacute"}, // й - lowercase e, acute accent
        {"\u00EA", "ecirc"},  // к - lowercase e, circumflex accent
        {"\u00EB", "euml"},   // л - lowercase e, umlaut
        {"\u00EC", "igrave"}, // м - lowercase i, grave accent
        {"\u00ED", "iacute"}, // н - lowercase i, acute accent
        {"\u00EE", "icirc"},  // о - lowercase i, circumflex accent
        {"\u00EF", "iuml"},   // п - lowercase i, umlaut
        {"\u00F0", "eth"},    // р - lowercase eth, Icelandic
        {"\u00F1", "ntilde"}, // с - lowercase n, tilde
        {"\u00F2", "ograve"}, // т - lowercase o, grave accent
        {"\u00F3", "oacute"}, // у - lowercase o, acute accent
        {"\u00F4", "ocirc"},  // ф - lowercase o, circumflex accent
        {"\u00F5", "otilde"}, // х - lowercase o, tilde
        {"\u00F6", "ouml"},   // ц - lowercase o, umlaut
        {"\u00F7", "divide"}, // Division sign
        {"\u00F8", "oslash"}, // ш - lowercase o, slash
        {"\u00F9", "ugrave"}, // щ - lowercase u, grave accent
        {"\u00FA", "uacute"}, // ъ - lowercase u, acute accent
        {"\u00FB", "ucirc"},  // ы - lowercase u, circumflex accent
        {"\u00FC", "uuml"},   // ь - lowercase u, umlaut
        {"\u00FD", "yacute"}, // э - lowercase y, acute accent
        {"\u00FE", "thorn"},  // ю - lowercase thorn, Icelandic
        {"\u00FF", "yuml"},   // я - lowercase y, umlaut
    };

    private static final int MIN_ESCAPE = 2;
    private static final int MAX_ESCAPE = 6;

    private static final HashMap<String, CharSequence> lookupMap;
    static {
        lookupMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
        for (final CharSequence[] seq : ESCAPES)
            lookupMap.put(seq[1].toString(), seq[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Recently, I had to optimize a slow Struts project. It turned out that under the cover Struts calls Apache for html string escaping by default (`<s:property value="..."/>`). Turning off escaping (`<s:property value="..." escaping="false"/>`) got some pages to run  5% to 20% faster.

Comment: A StringWriter uses a StringBuffer internally which uses locking. Using a StringBuilder directly should be faster.

Comment: found a bug in the above code when encountering "&#61;" aka =. writer.write(entityValue); should be writer.write(Character.toString((char)entityValue)); – Stevko 4 hours ago

Comment: @NickFrolov, your comments seem a bit messed up. `auml` is for instance `ä` and not `д`.

Comment: Improved version with all HTML5 characters: https://gist.github.com/MarkJeronimus/798c452582e64410db769933ec71cfb7

Comment: v2 in my gist (link above ↑). Works the same but has smaller class file footprint and shorter compile time. If there are issues, v1 is in the gist edit history.

Answer (score 18):

## Spring Framework HtmlUtils

If you're using Spring framework already, use the following method:

```
import static org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape;

...

String result = htmlUnescape(source);
```

Answer (score 17):

The following library can also be used for HTML escaping in Java: [unbescape](http://www.unbescape.org/).

HTML can be unescaped this way:

```
final String unescapedText = HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml(escapedText);
```

Comment: It did nothing to this: `%3Chtml%3E%0D%0A%3Chead%3E%0D%0A%3Ctitle%3Etest%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0D%0A%3Cbody%3E%0D%0Atest%0D%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E`

Comment: @ThreaT Your text is not html-encoded, it is url-encoded.

Answer (score 12):

This did the job for me,

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
...
String decodedXML = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(encodedXML);
```

Or

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
...
String decodedXML = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(encodedXML);
```

I guess it’s always better to use the `lang3` for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple, but inefficient solution without any external library is:

```
public static String unescapeHtml3(String str) {
    try {
        HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();
        new HTMLEditorKit().read(new StringReader("<html><body>" + str), doc, 0);
        return doc.getText(1, doc.getLength());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return str;
    }
}
```

This should be used only if you have only small count of string to decode.

Comment: Very close, but not exact - it converted "qwAS12ƷƸǅǚǪǼȌ" to "qwAS12ƷƸǅǚǪǼȌ\n".

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way is with

```
String cleanedString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(originalString);
```

from `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils`.

And to escape the whitespaces

```
cleanedString = cleanedString.trim();
```

This will ensure that whitespaces due to copy and paste in web forms to not get persisted in DB.

Answer (score 1):

**StringEscapeUtils (Apache Commons Lang)**
Escapes and unescapes Strings for Java, JavaScript, HTML, and XML.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
....
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(comment);
```

**Reference:** https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [HtmlManipulator](http://gmailassistant.sourceforge.net/src/org/freeshell/zs/common/HtmlManipulator.java.html) Java class. You may need to add some items (not all entities are in the list).

The [Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) StringEscapeUtils as [suggested by Kevin Hakanson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/how-can-i-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java/994339#994339) did not work 100% for me; several entities, like &#145 (left single quote) were translated into '222' somehow. I also tried *org.jsoup*, and had the same problem.

Comment: 222 is likely in octal (hexadecimal 0x92. decimal 146). In [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout) (but not in [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)), 0x92 corresponds to U+2019 ([RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)). Are you sure it is not octal 221? Or right single quote?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use the replace method by testing every entity in every variable. My code looks like this:

```
text = text.replace("&Ccedil;", "Ç");
text = text.replace("&ccedil;", "ç");
text = text.replace("&Aacute;", "Á");
text = text.replace("&Acirc;", "Â");
text = text.replace("&Atilde;", "Ã");
text = text.replace("&Eacute;", "É");
text = text.replace("&Ecirc;", "Ê");
text = text.replace("&Iacute;", "Í");
text = text.replace("&Ocirc;", "Ô");
text = text.replace("&Otilde;", "Õ");
text = text.replace("&Oacute;", "Ó");
text = text.replace("&Uacute;", "Ú");
text = text.replace("&aacute;", "á");
text = text.replace("&acirc;", "â");
text = text.replace("&atilde;", "ã");
text = text.replace("&eacute;", "é");
text = text.replace("&ecirc;", "ê");
text = text.replace("&iacute;", "í");
text = text.replace("&ocirc;", "ô");
text = text.replace("&otilde;", "õ");
text = text.replace("&oacute;", "ó");
text = text.replace("&uacute;", "ú");
```

In my case this worked very well.

Comment: This isn't every special entity.  Even the two mentioned in the question are missing.

Comment: this will not scale well

Answer (score -7):

In case you want to mimic what PHP function [htmlspecialchars_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) does, use PHP function [get_html_translation_table()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php) to dump the table and then use the Java code like,

```
static Map<String, String> html_specialchars_table = new Hashtable<String, String>();

static {
    html_specialchars_table.put("&lt;", "<");
    html_specialchars_table.put("&gt;", ">");
    html_specialchars_table.put("&amp;", "&");
}

static String htmlspecialchars_decode_ENT_NOQUOTES(String s) {
    Enumeration en = html_specialchars_table.keys();
    while(en.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = en.nextElement();
        String val = html_specialchars_table.get(key);
        s = s.replaceAll(key, val);
    }
    return s;
}
```