# How to convert encoded email address in Java?

Tags: java

If I receive an `emailAddress` in the following format:

```
example%40gmail.com
```

In Java how do I convert it to this:

```
example@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [URLDecoder.decode(String s, String enc)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) becuase URLDecoder.decode(String s) is deprecated in Java 1.5.

Here is the code to test your case:

```
@Test
public void testUrlDecoder() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String encodedStr = "example%40gmail.com";
    String decodedStr = URLDecoder.decode(encodedStr, "UTF-8");
    assertEquals("example@gmail.com", decodedStr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the answer to this question: [Java: How to unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you want, I haven't had a chance to test it to make sure that what you have is actually a url encoded item:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit simplistic, but you could try:

```
email = myEmailAddress.getAddress();
email.replace("%40", "@");
myEmailAddress.setAddress(email);
```

Comment: I don't know that this would work in all cases, though (probably not), so one of the other answers using decoders is better.