# Java regex conversion

Tags: java, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How to decode HTML character entities in Java like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

I have string data with some special characters encoded in this format `&#039`

in this case that encoding is a ' sign, a single quote.

so example the `"the citizen&#039s home"` should appear like `"the citizen's home"` but it does not.

Unfortunately this is not interpreted as such, and I need to parse all of my string for these things and convert them

first: what is that format called, this will help me find a conversion method

second: do you know of a method to fix my strings?

Comment: This format is called : HTML Entity (in decimal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel: Apache Commons Lang's [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) is what you want.

> Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing
>   the actual Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes. Supports
>   HTML 4.0 entities.
>
> For example, the string `"&lt;Fran&ccedil;ais&gt;"` will become
>   `"<Français>"`
>
> If an entity is unrecognized, it is left alone, and inserted verbatim
>   into the result string. e.g. `"&gt;&zzzz;x"` will become `">&zzzz;x"`.