# Problems parsing Spanish characters (á, é, í, ó, ú) from XML response

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing

I'm developing a Java app, that calls a PHP from internet that it's giving me a XML response.

In the response is contained this word: "Próximo", but when i parse the nodes of the XML and obtain the response into a String variable, I'm receiving the word like this: "Pr&oacute;ximo".

How can i solve this?

Comment: These are not  rare characters, they are Spanish characters.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode

Comment: Pableras84 is calling a php script not belonging to him from a java app or did i get it wrong? The question is tagged java

Comment: What encoding are you using in PHP script and what in your Java app? Does that XML file generated by PHP look ok when you show it in browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: kdb, it's free to use that in a commercial app??? i must do something to use that? for example link to apache or something?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using different encoding in your Java app then encoding of PHP script. Try to set encoding of your stream, for example like that

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://www.yourpage.com/");
URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        yc.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));//<-- here you set encoding
                                                     //to the same as in your PHP
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this problem... While parsing use  "ISO-8859-1"  format and use Html.fromHtml(string) method while storing your values into bean .Where "string" is the value inside the each tag of XML response.