# how to decode html codes using Java?

Tags: java, html, regex, decode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How to decode HTML character entities in Java like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

I need to extract paragraphs (like `title` in StackOverflow) from an `html` file.

I can use regular expressions in Java to extract the fields I need but I have to `decode` the fields obtained.

**EXAMPLE**

field extracted:

```
Paging Lucene&#39s search results (with **;** among **&#39** and **s**)
```

field after decoding:

```
Paging Lucene's search results
```

Is there any class in java that will allow me to convert these html codes?

Comment: Does your HTML contain tags?

Comment: Yes, but the field extracted doesn't contain tags

Comment: For starters, [using regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) is utterly wrong in first place. Just use a [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers) like Jsoup. A bit decent one would immediately already unescape HTML for you.

Answer (score 31):

Use methods provided by [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
// ...
String afterDecoding = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(beforeDecoding);
```

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml(java.lang.String) - Latest link

Answer (score 3):

Do **not try to solve everything by regexp**.

While you can do some parts - such as replacing entities, the **much better approach** is to actually use a (robust) **HTML parser**.

See this question: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
for why this is a bad idea to do with the regexp swiss army chainsaw. **Seriously, read this question and the top answer, it is a *stack overflow highlight*!**

> Chuck Norris *can* parse HTML with regex.

The bad news is: **there is more than one way** to encode characters.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML

> For example, the character 'λ' can be represented as `&#955;`, `&#x03BB;` or `&#X03bb;`

And if you are really unlucky, some web site relies on some browsers capabilities to guess character meanings. `&#153;` for example is not valid, yet many browsers will interpret it as `™`.

**Clearly it is a good idea to leave this to a dedicated library instead of trying to hack a custom regular expression yourself.**

So I strongly recommend:

- Feed string into a robust HTML parser
- Get parsed (and fully decoded) string back

Comment: I need to extract from htmls with same structures and tags (like wikipedia). So I think regex is a good approach.

Comment: @MrCarAsus: NO IT IS NOT. Use a HTML parser, and DOM for extraction. That is what they are for!

Comment: Try using DBPedia, btw. It is an already parsed version of Wikipedia.

Comment: And do you know a parsed version of StackOverflow? I try to use regex with stackoverflow htmls and it works. I extract title and answers with a set of regexps applied on htlm.

Comment: Use an HTML parser. Every time you rape HTML with a regexp parsing attempt, god kills a kitten.

Comment: Seriously, read [using Regexp to parse HTML is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). HTML is a Chomsky Type 2 language, and Regexp is of type 3. You need a Type 2 parser.

Comment: Plus **there are plenty of HTML parsers around**. Why don't you just try using them? The StackOverflow data dump is also quite well pre-parsed, btw. - you can get a lot of information out of it with a simple XML pull parser, and not having to do anything yourself.

Comment: Re "`&#153;` for example is not valid" is perfectly valid though possibly interpreted inconsistently by user-agents?  [Section 4.6 of HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#dec-charref) puts no bounds on the codepoints that can be represented by decimal numeric character references and that codepoint is a [valid control character codepoint](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).

Comment: @MikeSamuel The page says in number 3: "**not** ... in the range U+0080–U+009F". 0x0099 is in this range.