# How to can I parse with Jsoup in Android?

Tags: php, android, jsoup

I cannot get the data of [this](http://android-forum.hu/feed.php) with Jsoup. It can connect if I use this:

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("http://android-forum.hu/feed.php");
```

But if I want to get the site data I got this exeption:

```
org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml. Mimetype=application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8, URL=http://android-forum.hu/feed.php
```

I use this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://android-forum.hu/feed.php").get();
```

So I want to get the page data. How to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UnsupportedMimeTypeException`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/UnsupportedMimeTypeException.html) is thrown when the minetype of the response is not supported.

You can use `ignoreContentType(true)` to let Jsoup ignore minetype, try

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://android-forum.hu/feed.php")
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .get();
```

(*call it before `.get`*)

Comment: Also if the data contains unsupported character like "á" how to write to the screen? Because I got "&" or ";" or something like that...

Comment: If you get the HTML encoding chars, just decode them check this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750290/how-to-decode-html-codes-using-java