# Convert HTML-escaped strings to plain Unicode/ASCII

Tags: java, android, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How to decode HTML character entities in Java like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

is there a Java/Android way to convert HTML-escaped strings (such as `&Ouml;` or `&szlig;`) back to their ASCII/Unicode representations (such as `Ö` or `ß`)?

I of course do not want to do a simple string-replacement and try with just every HTML-escape-sequence that exists, I'd guess there is a ready-to use solution?

Thanks!

Comment: `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(myHtmlString)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class StringEscapeUtilsTrial {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strHTMLInput = "<p>MyName<p>";
    String strEscapeHTML = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(strHTMLInput);
    String strUnEscapeHTML = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(strEscapeHTML);
    System.out.println("Escaped HTML >>> " + strEscapeHTML);
    System.out.println("UnEscaped HTML >>> " + strUnEscapeHTML);
    }
}
```