# Print html tags inside System Output in Grails test report

Tags: html, grails, groovy

I'm trying to print the step's descriptions of my Spock specs in my **grails** tests reports.

I'm using `print/println` to make this information available in the reports.

The issue is that I want to print some data as an HTML table, but when I print some html tag (i.e. `<table>`), the `<` and `>` (less then and greater than signs) are printed as `&lt` and `&gt`.

Is there a way to print the tags without transforming the tags?

Comment: Try `"the string".decodeAsHTML()`

Comment: I get following exception:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.decodeAsHTML() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: decodeHex()

Answer (score 1):

There is a answer here: [Java: How to unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode) , which recommend using [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(String str)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) .

> unescapeHtml
>
> public static String unescapeHtml(String str)
>
> ```
> Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing the actual
> ```
>
> Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes.
>   Supports HTML 4.0 entities.
>
> ```
> For example, the string "&lt;Fran&ccedil;ais&gt;" will become "<Français>"
>
> If an entity is unrecognized, it is left alone, and inserted verbatim into
> ```
>
> the result string. e.g. ">&zzzz;x" will become
>   ">&zzzz;x".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although, I tried it and it doesn't solved the problem, I think there's some kind of filter that transform the string before it is displayed.