# Want to replace special characters with equivalent UTF-8 symbols

Tags: java, xml

As part of my application I have written a custom method to extract data from the DB and return it as a string. My string has special characters like the pound sign, which when extracted looks like this:

> "MyMobile Blue &#163;54.99 [12 month term]"

I want the &#163; to be replaced with actual pound symbol. Below is my method:

```
public String getOfferName(String offerId) {
    log(Level.DEBUG, "Entered getSupOfferName");
    OfferClient client = (OfferClient) ApplicationContext
            .get(OfferClient.class);
    OfferObject offerElement = getOfferElement(client, offerId);
    if (offerElement == null) {
        return "";
    } else {

        return offerElement.getDisplayValue();
    }
}
```

Can some one help on this?

Comment: Why do you think that you don't already have the real Unicode character for  £?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode) should help. Link in post seems dead - [here's](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml(java.lang.String)) one that works.

Comment: @bmargulies - have edited. The OP has the HTML (XML) entity for £.

Comment: @bmorris591 post an answer?

Comment: Is the input XML or HTML? The parser should be responsible for the conversion, not you.

Answer (score 2):

The document contains [XML/HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) .

You can use the [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) method from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to parse these back to their unicode equivalents.

If this is HTML rather than XML use the [other methods](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) as there are differences in the two sets of entities.

Answer (score 0):

I voted for StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml() solution. Anyway, here's is a custom solution

```
    String s = "MyMobile Blue &#163;54.99 [12 month term]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&#(\\d+?);");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()) {
        int c = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "" + (char)c);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb);
```

output

```
MyMobile Blue £54.99 [12 month term]
```

note that it does not accept hex entity reference