# Problems with HTML content in generated PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, itextpdf

I am generating a PDF from HTML, but instead of interpreting it as normal text my PDF pages are filled with html tags like `<p>`, `<li>`, etc.

Comment: html content like <p>,<table>,<nbsp> etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to remove all tags and unescape special chars.

PHP example:

```
$text = preg_replace($html, '<[^>]*>', '');
$text = html_entity_decode($text);
```

VB.NET example:

```
Dim text As String = Regex.Replace(html, "<[^>]*>", "")
text = System.Web.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text)
```

Java example:

```
text = html.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

For the html entity decoding you'll find a good answer here: [Java: How to unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode). Otherwise you could just replace them if you know all of them (`&nbsp;`, `&quot;`, ...).

Comment: I am using itext java for generating pdf.Can you please give an example for it.