# Need help on publishing xml data webpage (it should publish "^~\&amp;|" instead of "^~\&|")

Tags: html, xml, jsp

I have XML data in oracle database and extracting using servlet class and publishing data on HTML webpage. But in one of the tag value on webpage it is showing as "`^~\&|`", but it should publish as "`^~\&amp;|`". How can I do that? I mean I want to publish as it as the xml from database on to webpage. Please suggest.

```
<div id="payloadMsg${count.index}">${msg.messagePayload}</div> </div>
```

I am pulling data from database using servlet class and then using JSP I am publishing data. Actual data in database contains amp, so i want to same data publish as it as on webpage. Any one can help?

Comment: If the data you get contain “&” and you want to display (I guess that’s what “publish” means here) as “&amp;”, then you need to convert any `&` in the data to `&amp;amp;`. But do you mean something more complicated?

Comment: Jukka - Actual data in database contains "&amp;", but when I publish on web page it is converting as "&". So I want exact data as it is stored to database. I mean i want actual data which contains "&amp;". Please help.

Comment: (Referenced from a comment on my answer) What *is* wrong when using `${fn:escapeXml(msg.messagePayload)}`?

Comment: Jukka - Do you have any suggesion?

Comment: If the data you get from the database is actually `&amp;` and you wish to have it rendered literally, then you need to convert the `&` in it into `&amp;`. This is what you generally need to do if you want to display entity references (character references) literally in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As revealed in the comments, the source data in this case *incorrectly* (?) contains a mixture of encoded entity references (e.g. for `<`, `>`) and un-encoded entities (i.e. for `&`). Find out *why* this unfortunate situation is occuring.

The *correct* solution is to fix the data and then - *always* - perform the escaping as `${fn:escapeXml(theRawData)}`. That is, instead of replacing `&` with `&amp;` to emulate proper encoding, simply fix/unescape the data first - such as when it's read from the database, or go through and correct/update the data in the database - and then use the corrected data.

In this case, the "fix" function might be as trivial as replacing `&lt;` with `<` and replacing all `&gt;` with `>` since they are the "affected" characters. Alternatively, there are [existing approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode) for handling such entity conversions; yet the *cause* for this [partial] double-encoding needs to be identified, and it might be the result of improper XML-in-XML usage.

---

The data in `${msg.messagePayload}` *should* be ["HTML escaped"](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#use) before it is written to the HTML output, however the given environment allows for that. (XML is a bit different, but the issue and fix is "close enough" here.)

The problem with `&amp;` in the data being rendered as `&` is `&amp;` *is* the [entity reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Character_and_entity_references) for `&`. Thus the data needs to be written to the HTML stream as `&amp;amp;`. (Similar situations exists for characters like `<` and sometimes `>`, which is why escaping should *always* be done!)

Comment: Actual data in database contains "&amp;", but when I publish on web page it is converting as "&". So I want exact data as it is stored in database. So please help. Here my code is: <c:otherwise> <c:forEach items="${msgs}" var="msg" varStatus="count"> <tr id="check"> <td>${msg.dob}</td> <td>${msg.name}</td> <td><div class="accordion"> <h3>Payload</h3> <div id="payloadMsg${count.index}">${msg.messagePayload}</div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="msgType${count.index}">${msg.messageType}</div> </td> </tr> </c:forEach></c:otherwise>

Comment: @user3311215 I've explained the basic problem above - which accounts for "what is stored" and "why it's converted" - and the general solution. Please refer to the links for additional details.

Comment: I tried to use ${fn:escapeXml(msg.messagePayload)}, but it is changing all xml characters. Please help me how to get exact data as it was in database.

Comment: I am researching from morning, but not found any related data. Can you please suggest?

Comment: @user3311215 Start with updating the question to include the relevant *environment* being used - JSP? Also, I'm curious what "changing all xml characters" means, or why it is .. bad.

Comment: Yex, it is in JSP. My servlet class pull data from database and my JSP class will publish data.

Comment: If i use escapeXML function it is replacing all <, >, &  with &lt; &rt; everywhere.

Comment: See my answer for how to handle amp alone.

Comment: @user3311215 Look at - and update the question to include - the *actual* data read from the database. It contains an odd mixture of escaped and unescaped entities. I suggest fixing the data after identifying why this is the case, and *always* escaping raw data emitted. I've updated my reply with some additional information and suggestions.

Comment: Here the xml data from database and on webpage:

From database and servlet: <MSH><EncodingCharacters>^~\&amp;|</EncodingCharacters> <MSH>

On JSP webpage: <MSH><tns:EncodingCharacters>^~\&|</tns:EncodingCharacters></MSH>

I want to print on webpage same as database: <EncodingCharacters>^~\&amp;|</EncodingCharacters>

Comment: user2864740 - In simple term I just want to publish as it is (same message) on webpage. In the database it has: <EncodingCharacters>^~\&amp;|</EncodingCharacters> <MSH>, but on webpage it is publishing <MSH><EncodingCharacters>^~\&|</EncodingCharacters></MSH> .

Comment: user2864740 - As developerwjk user suggested I changed in servlet class where I am setting the value. It seems to be working now. Let me keep testing my all scenarios, if I have any issues I will get you back. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @user3311215 Cool, I'm glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

In the controller that's setting the value for `${msg.messagePayload}`, before forwarding, do:

```
msg.messagePayload = msg.messagePayload.replaceAll("&amp;", "&amp;amp;");
```

or

```
msg.messagePayload = msg.messagePayload.replaceAll("&", "&amp;amp;");
```

whichever works.

Comment: developerwjk - In the jsp I am publishing data like here. Where can I add here, sorry. I confused. <c:otherwise> <c:forEach items="${msgs}" var="msg" varStatus="count"> <tr id="check"> <td>${msg.dob}</td> <td>${msg.name}</td> <td><div class="accordion"> <h3>Payload</h3> <div id="payloadMsg${count.index}">${msg.messagePayload}</div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="msgType${count.index}">${msg.messageType}</div> </td> </tr> </c:forEach></c:otherwise>

Comment: I'm not sure if you can put it inside EL syntax like `${msg.messagePayload.replaceAll("&amp;", "&amp;amp;")}` or not. If you're using pure JSP/JSTL with no controller, I don't know.

Comment: Here the xml data from database and on webpage:

From database and servlet: <MSH><EncodingCharacters>^~\&amp;|</EncodingCharacters> <MSH>

On JSP webpage: <MSH><tns:EncodingCharacters>^~\&|</tns:EncodingCharacters></MSH>

I want to print on webpage same as database: <EncodingCharacters>^~\&amp;|</EncodingCharacters>

Comment: I am using servlet to pull data from database and then my JSP will publish that data by calling servlet class. I am getting correct data in servlet, only problem is on JSP page.

Comment: developerwjk - Thank you. I changed in servlet class where I am setting the value. It seems to be working now. Let me keep testing my all scenarios, if I have any issues I will get you back. Thanks again...