# XML Sax parser doesn't parse as supposed. XML-file seems fine

Tags: java, android, xml, sax

My sax parser is working fine for other xml files, however for this file it's not working. [Before formatting](https://gist.github.com/jakkra/f0a22336ccfa2727d4da) and [after xml file formatted](https://gist.github.com/jakkra/cd9d6a90d9bb3ade1c91)

I can't find what's wrong in the XML code, some online validators says it's ok, and some doesn't.

I have put a print in the `startElement method()` and it just writes

```
 @Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attribute) {
    elementOn = true;
    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
    if (localName.equals("Part")) {
        journey.add(sb.toString())
    ...
    }


03-03 11:50:04.165    3165-3184/se.xxx.x.app E/start﹕ [ 03-03 11:50:04.165  3165: 3184 E/start    ]
03-03 11:50:04.165    3165-3184/se.xxx.x.app E/start﹕ [ 03-03 11:50:04.165  3165: 3184 E/start    ]
03-03 11:50:04.165    3165-3184/se.xxx.x.app E/start﹕ [ 03-03 11:50:04.165  3165: 3184 E/start    ]
```

I also put one print in the `endElement method` and it writes this:

```
03-03 12:11:17.114    3257-3276/se.x.x.app E/endElement﹕ <Part><From><Id>80129</Id><Poi>A</Poi><PoiAlias>A</PoiAlias><Name>Malmö Ellstorp</Name><X>6167351.00</X><Y>1324920.00</Y></From><To><Id>80110</Id><Poi>G</Poi><PoiAlias>G</PoiAlias><Name>Malmö Värnhem</Name><X>6167569.00</X><Y>1324648.00</Y></To><Line><Name>3</Name><No>3</No><LinTName>Stadsbuss</LinTName></Line><Coords><Coord><X>6167348.97</X><Y>1324918.92</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167395.11</X><Y>1324877.70</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167407.62</X><Y>1324865.61</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167422.52</X><Y>1324852.10</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167444.33</X><Y>1324832.65</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167467.42</X><Y>1324811.56</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167484.12</X><Y>1324795.79</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167496.59</X><Y>1324782.39</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167521.95</X><Y>1324757.39</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167530.16</X><Y>1324749.31</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167536.06</X><Y>1324742.80</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167528.65</X><Y>1324734.64</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167518.76</X><Y>1324727.43</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167508.90</X><Y>1324719.42</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167513.49</X><Y>1324710.15</Y></Coord><Coord><X>6167563.87</X><Y>1324644.56</Y></Coord></Coords></Part>
```

Which is the whole "Part" block, it doesn't find each element in it.

Full xml parser if necessary [full handler class](https://gist.github.com/jakkra/4943b247a37e47d546d3)

EDIT: Here is the raw data I use: [XML URL](http://www.labs.skanetrafiken.se/v2.2/journeypath.asp?cf=1492979959618199152&id=0)
EDIT: If I copy and past my xml from Chrome into a String and parse it from there it works fine.

```
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            xmlR.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream())); //Does not work
            --------
            InputSource stream = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));// Works if I go to that URL in Chrome and copy the xml into the String xml.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file includes the string "Malmö" which includes a non-ASCII character. This points strongly to an encoding problem. There's no XML declaration to specify the encoding of the file, so the parser will probably guess it's encoded in UTF-8. If that assumption turns out to be wrong, parsing is likely to fail.

You need to look not only at how this string is encoded, but also at what happens to the data between leaving the disk and reaching the XML parser. There are plenty of ways of losing encoding information on that short journey.

Comment: Solved, the server send me stuff like  "&gt;" instead of <, >, even tho it said it was using utf-8 (mixed utf-8 and something else). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode