# How can I delete all special symbols like &mdash; &nbsp; and others from non-html string?

Tags: java, html-parsing

How to delete all special symbols like  & mdash; & nbsp; and others from non-html string? I have a java String object with this garbage. I need to remove all the special strings like & mdash; & nbsp; & laquo; & raquo; etc. How to do it with java? I don't have an html string.

Comment: So you're looking to remove any substring that consists of an ampersand, followed by a handful of letters, followed by a semicolon; is that right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331

Comment: beresfordt, I think this is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

use replaceAll method of the string.

```
String str = ...
str =str.replaceAll("&nbsp;"," "); //changes &nbsp to space
```

If you just want to remove all of them (replace with ""). To deal with all the unwanted sequences in one go, define the requex patter, and use it to remove the sequences.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(...)
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
str = m.replaceAll("");
```