# In java, using stringName.contains() isn't working with special character codes

Tags: java, string, character, contains

I'm working with an HTML doc that contains the word "Español", however in the source code it's written as "Espa&# 241;ol" (Space added so it's not automatically changed by your browser)

If I do something like this, the "Español" is NOT found:

```
        if (source.contains("Espa&#241;ol")) 
        System.out.println("Found it");
```

If I do this, the word IS found:

```
        if (source.contains("Español")) 
        System.out.println("Found it");
```

Can anyone provide insight into what's going on?

Comment: Either `"Espa\u00F1ol"` or nowadays use UTF-8 for editing and compiling, and type `"Español"`. By the way decimal 241 = hexadecimal 0xF1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting text from HTML, you need to convert HTML-escaped characters (such as `&#241;`) into Unicode characters (`ñ`) first. Good approach is to use **[Apache Commons Lang library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)**.

In your case:

```
input = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(input);
```

will perform HTML->Unicode transformation.

Answer (score 3):

The top piece of code uses the HTML encoding for the ñ character, the bottom piece does not.  The .contains() method searches for the exact input string, meaning the top piece of code is searching for the *exact* string, "Espa&# 241;ol", which cannot be found, since it is not in the String source.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however it's the opposite that is happening. The source contains the HTML encoding, and yet attempting to search for if "Espa&# 241;ol" does not work. Yet, searching for "Español" does work.

Comment: When java converts the document text to a string, it probably parses that encoding into an actual character, rather than the encoding

Answer (score 1):

You will need to un-escape the characters before checking.

Quoting [Kevin Hakanson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22514/kevin-hakanson) answer from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

> You can use the Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) for
>   this.

So in your case, provided that you've added the Apache Commons Lang library, the following code snippet should work as expected:

```
if (source.contains(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("Espa&#241;ol"))) 
    System.out.println("Found it");
```