# Inserting and displaying mathematical symbols in j2ee web application

Tags: java

I have mathematical symbols e.g. **alfa**, **beta**,**mu** . When I copy these symbols in text area they are getting copied. I am copying them from word document. When I insert them into the database using prepared statement the symbols are getting inserted as code. for example the **alfa** is getting stored as `&#946;`. This is fine I guess. But when I retrieve them from the database using java.sq.Statement and displaying them in the html page they are getting displayed as code instead of symbol. I mean `"&#946;"` is displayed in html instead displaying alfa symbol. So how to deal with this situation? how can I store symbols and display them properly in html?

I am using mysql database, java1.7,struts2.0  and tomcat7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to decode HTML character entities in Java like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

Comment: can you share the html code of this alpha part?

Comment: <tr >
            
 <td align="left">&amp;#946;</td>             </tr>

Comment: Your Problem is the &amp;. It Must be a &. Just use StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()!

Answer (score 1):

The correct display of HTML characters is: `&#946;` (Looks like: β) You need to add a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

1) How are you displaying the codes in HTML?

2) What is the char encoding of machine your are running your server/viewing your html

I had following code and it worked

`<html>
<body>
This is alpha &#945;<br/>
This is beta &#946; <br/>
This is gamma &#915; <br/>
<body>
</html>` as shown below:

This is alpha α
This is beta β 
This is gamma Γ

You may need to declare your charset:

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

or see the encoding of your server (if its in jsp)

Comment: yes it is a jsp. but i have added <meta> tag as shown by you in the adding page and display page but the code is getting displayed as &amp;#946;  so how can i deal with this. i see the value of the Alfa symbol in the database it is correct only. it is &#946;. but when i retrieve them through java.sql.statement interface and displaying in the jsp page it is getting displayed as &amp;#946; so how can i deal with this?

Comment: @MuralidharYaragalla Can you share your jsp code how you are showing the date. It may be converting & to &amp; 

Try like:

 <%
   request.setAttribute("specialCharString", "&#946;");
    %>
  
    HTML: ${specialCharString}

And see what it prints.

Comment: @MuralidharYaragalla
So now you got the idea how u can display your characters from DB. Get it in some string and display it. If required, you may need to unescape string

Answer (score 0):

The following tag of struts helped me solving this to an extent.

```
<s:property value="name" escape="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're using JSPs. Add this import on top of your JSP which is rendering the symbols:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```