# Html entity decoder java

Tags: java, html

I have a string like this:

नमस्कार

Now i want to translate the string to html entity decoder. I can translate manually by using

url https://mothereff.in/html-entities

is there any java api to translate it ?
can anyone help me ? thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to decode HTML character entities in Java like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might prove to be useful [unbescape](http://www.unbescape.org/index.html). I found it to be diverse and very quick to implement. I'm using it to convert huge lists of strings with HTML entities in them back to normal strings. It's quick and accurate so far.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, after a quick google search, that a popular solution to this is using [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29). More information can be found in this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode) question.