# How to convert encoded character for supporting multi byte character in java?

Tags: java, soapui, multibyte

I am getting characters like this while executing the web service from
soap-ui:

```
&amp;#20975;&amp;#40857
```

How can I decode them ? 
The exact value should be  in Chinese language
and value will be  **凯龙** in place of these encoded character.

Comment: Those are HTML entities; I'm sure there's a library, or code samples, somewhere, to do that for you... Also, you are "getting characters", how? In a string?

Comment: Yes, In a string i am getting these values..? I am not sure much about either this is HTML entities or something else. my expected result should be that Chinese value what i mentioned above. using java code i have to code inside  function in java file.

Comment: Well then, grab the numbers behind `&#` and `;` (those are code points; see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20975/index.htm) for the first of them) and use `Character.toChars()`.

Comment: `new String(new char[]{20975,40857})` is `"凯龙"`.

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer [how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode#994339)

Comment: In what context are you getting these?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually normal. Good parser suppose to understand it. For example if you open this xml in a browser you will see as shown below.

[image]

Some security libraries like ESAPI from owasp to strict about escaping rules and do that coding. Meanwhile  w3.org don't recommend to use it since you can't read such message in simple text editor and some other cases.

Some information in [here](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes)

Simple way to unescape is to use `apache commons library` class [StringEscapeUtil](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.htmlhttps://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)