# How to decode hexadecimal HTML entities in Android?

Tags: android, html

I decode HTML entities using:

```
String total_string = Html.fromHtml(result).toString();
```

But it doesn't work for hex entitites.

```
// decimal &#38;  - works
// hex &#x26; - does not work
```

What should I do to decode?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode