# How to convert from alt codes to unicodes characters to print the correct symbol?

Tags: java, unicode

I have **alt codes** stored in DB for example `&#163;`.

Now I want to read this from DB and print the symbol beloinging to this, e.g., the symbol `£`.

But when I store the DB value in String, I get the alt code (`&#163;`) and not the sign which is how it works. But I need the symbol.

Unfortunately **I can't change the DB to store unicodes** and much more unfortunate is that **I'm on Java 1.3** and **I can't use any third party library**.

Is there a solution to what I need?

Comment: When you say "I can't use any third party library", is that also stopping you from copying the Java file you need from said library? For example https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java  Alternatively someone has already written a class that does what you need here too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24575417/6391367

Comment: Why are you on Java 1.**3** anyway? Thats from the year ***2000***!

Comment: Thanks Arizzle ! But these use so much post java 1.3 :(

Comment: @Clashsoft it's some old non-beneficial tool I'm working on