# How to decode the special characters sent from the url in Java?

Tags: java

I am sending the the value from my jsp to my servlet in url parsing.

The value contains the special character `()`, but when I am receiving the value it is `&#40` and `&#41`.

How to decode this back to `()`?

jsp code

```
var devicename=document.getElementById('s_loc_1').value;    
    var param=devicename;
    param=encodeURIComponent(devicename);
    var updatedevsaturl="http://"+window.location.host+"/services/PCEquipmentDevice?productid={}&action=updatePCDeviceStatus&reqby={}&param="+param;
    var productId=document.getElementById('pid').value;
    updatedevsaturl=sustituteParameter(updatedevsaturl,productId);
    updatedevsaturl=sustituteParameter(updatedevsaturl,userUpi);
    alert(updatedevsaturl);
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        timeout:20000,
        url : updatedevsaturl,
        async: false,
        dataType : "xml",
        success: function(data) {   }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Service Unavailable - VPU List');
        }
    });
```

java code to decode

```
if(action.equals("updatePCDeviceStatus")){
        System.out.println("param: "+param);
        //String decodeparam3 = new String(param.getBytes("UTF-8"),"ASCII");
        //String decodeparam3 =URLDecoder.decode(param, "UTF-8");
        String decodeparam3= URLDecoder.decode(param, "ISO-8859-1");    
        System.out.println("decodeparam132 "+ decodeparam3);
```

I tried all the ways give on net but didnt workenter code here

input at jsp 2-in-1 Laptop (12.5 inches)
output at servlet 2-in-1 Laptop &#4012.5 inches&#41

Comment: for example my input is  2-in-1 Laptop (12.5 inches) and i getting on servlet is 2-in-1 Laptop &#40;12.5 inches&#41;

Comment: You haven't provided enough context to help you out. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This is not URL encoding. These are HTML escape sequences, and you should *not* be sending them like that from your JSP. Please post the form in the JSP that causes these characters to be sent.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24575417/1098603

Comment: In my jsp I am using the encodeURIComponent to encoded parameter and then I am send that parameter to a servlet by url parsing but when i am try to decode the same parameter it is not able to decode the special characters for example parameter- 2-in-1 Laptop (12.5 inches) with encoding after decoding at servlet 2-in-1 Laptop &#40;12.5 inches&#41;

Comment: (1) Don't *describe* your code, *post* your code. (2) To add information, [edit] the question and add the information.

Answer (score 0):

This is ASCII code for "(". Look at this answer [Java: How to unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java) . You have to create a char from that html entity.

Comment: Pardon? This is the answer