# How to disable encoding HTML in Java

Tags: java, html, encoding

```
    task.addText(comment);
```

This comment has HTML tags. So when we send this comment as mail, we see encoded HTML like this in mail:

```
<h3>asdasas as<b>asdasdas</b>dasdas<u>dasdasdasd<strike>asdasdasdsadasdasdas<span id="selectionBoundary_1493731518682_030677381665187298" class="rangySelectionBoundary"></span></strike></u></h3>
```

I want to see not tags, i want to see what tag does for UI.

This is from db of email for email body part:

```
 b&gt;asdasdas&lt;/b&gt;dasdas&lt;u&gt;dasdasdasd&lt;strike&gt;asdasdasdsadasdasdas&lt;span id=&quot;selectionBoundary_1493731518682_030677381665187298&quot; class=&quot;rangySelectionBoundary&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strike&gt;&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/h3&gt;</td>\n
```

this is html part of email:

```
<p th:if="${!commentsInTask.empty}">Tüm yorumlar: </p>
<table

    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="allComments : ${comments}">
    <tr th:each="comment : ${comments}">
    </tr>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

NOrmally there was no decoding but i saw from here

[Java: How to unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java)

and did this

```
comment=StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(comment);
```

but did not work.

this is from comment db:

```
<h3>asdasas as<b>asdasdas</b>dasdas<u>dasdasdasd<strike>asdasdasdsadasdasdas<span id="selectionBoundary_1493731518682_030677381665187298" class="rangySelectionBoundary"></span></strike></u></h3>
```

it is same as email db

But it should not have changed tags to &lt

So it means i want to escape html. I tried

```
escapeHtml but did not work.
```

or

```
HtmlEscapers.htmlEscaper().escape(comment)
```

also we have this while putting to html

```
Context context = new Context(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR"));
context.setVariables(comment);
```

and thymeleaf did not work. Converting to `<td th:utext is not working.`

It is happening between those

Context context = new Context(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR"));

```
context.setVariables(mail.getParams());

String process = templateEngine.process(mail, context);
```

because before

```
Context context = new Context(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR"));
```

there is nothing. after that line,

```
context.setVariables(mail.getParams());
```

it becoming decoded.

Comment: you should set the comment as innerHTML of a node on the HTML page rather than adding it as value of a text input.

Answer (score 0):

I think found it:

```
<td th:utext="${Comment}" th:remove="tag" >message ...</td>
```

added remove tag and utext