# Why does java can't recognize html text after submtting to Spring controller?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, urlencode

I send js variable to Spring controller by clicking button. 
That's what I have in js:

```
function submitArticle()
{
    var pdata= $('textarea').froalaEditor('html.get');
    $.post("/submitProject", pdata).done(function(response) {
        console.log("Response: " + pdata);
    });
}
```

So it works well, console.log displays next : `<h1>New Article</h1><p>Some text</p>`

but, that's what I get in Spring controller:

```
%3Ch1%3ENew+Article%3C%2Fh1%3E%3Cp%3ESome+text%3C%2Fp%3E=
```

It just replaces `<`, `>`,  and `/` to some codes. How to replace them to normal tags. Because I want to store this html code in java String.

My Spring Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/submitProject")
public ModelAndView submitProject(@RequestBody String html, @ModelAttribute(value = "LoggedUser") User user)
{
    System.out.println(html);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}
```

Comment: It's encoded HTML.  You have to decode it on the server side.  I would have guessed Spring would take care of it; you're doing something else wrong.  You should not want to store markup.  It's the data that matters.

Comment: @duffmo I offer a user an froala editor to create article with headers, paragraphs, images etc. It translates to html and store as a string in mongodb, then it just pastes to blank html page. That's how creating articles should work for me. That's why I need to store html as a string.

Comment: Then decode it as HTML and store it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `java.net.URLDecoder#decode` method.
When I ran the code you posted through it I was able to retrieve the original text

Answer (score 0):

Send as an object and receive a `Map`

```
$.post("/submitProject", {pdata})...
```

and

```
public ModelAndView submitProject(@RequestBody Map<String, String> data ...
// -> String html = data.get('pdata');
```