# text with escaped character codes

Tags: java, html, character

I have a html-text containing escaped charaters, which I would like replace into a nonescaped readable form:

Example:

```
&#39;bla bla &#39;
```

I know that 39 is just an ascii code for the character '.
I could simply parse the hole text, extract the code and write the corresponding character.

My Question. Is there any method from java base to do this ?

Comment: "method from java base" but why reinvent the wheel? Others already done it for us: [Java: How to unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/994331)

Comment: No, it's not the ASCII code; It's the Unicode codepoint. Another example, &#128690; 