# Handle HTML encoded data in Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I need to dynamically generate some bottoms based on the return of ajax get call

```
@.getJSON("SearchByName", {"name":searchstring}, function(data){
    data = data.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp");
    var pop = "<p>" + data + "</p><br/><button style=\"border-radius: 
    4px;\" onclick=getDatabyName(\"" + data +"\")>Load 
    Locations</button>";
    .....
```

Since the return data may have space so I have to replace all spaces with `&nbsp;`

When users press the generated bottom to execute `getDatabyName`, it calls a Servlet to query a database. However, the query within the Java Servlet returns nothing because the space characters are not properly encoded. I tried to do another replace inside `getDatabyName` but still the same. I have ways to work around this but want to know the proper ways (either in Javascript or in Java)  to handle this situation.

Comment: data = data.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp"); missing a semicolon it the original post

Comment: Just [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

See this post on how to fix your Java Servlet to decode HTML input:

[Java: How to unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java#994339)

PS. Change `&nbsp` to `&nbsp;` in your code.