# Proper decoding of server response

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, okhttp

In my app I use Retrofit+Gson to communicate with the server. However, there is encoding problem with the server response.
In OkHttp logging interceptor server response look like this, which is OK:

```
... "name":"S\u0026#39;mores" ...
```

This is part of server response JSON. When the response is deserialized by Gson, the deserialized string looks like this:

```
S&#39;mores
```

I'd like to know what's happening during deserialization and how to make Strings be encoded properly.
Below is my Retrofit initialization code:

```kotlin
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                    .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            )

mRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createAsync())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        mAPI = mRetrofit.create(PetfinderJSONAPI::class.java)
```

#### What I tried:

- Set `gson.disableHtmlEscaping()` and pass it to `GsonConverterFactory.create()`
- Add OkHttp Interceptor which sets `Accept-Charset: utf-8`
- Manually decode String before setting it to text field by `URLDecoder.decode()` and `Html.fromHtml()`

Neither of these helped. My strings are still not properly encoded.

EDIT: According to [this](https://codebeautify.org/html-decode-string) html decoder site, `&#39;` is decoded as `'`. Thus, I expect my decoded string to be `S'mores`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an answer for the similar older question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524583/10267053

Just like there, I created custom deserializer:

```kotlin
class HtmlDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Throws(JsonParseException::class)
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): String? {
        return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(json.asString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The unicode `\u0026` refers to hex value 26, or 38 in decimal. ASCII 38 indicates an Ampersand(&).
https://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Now I see that server sends HTML encoded data, which is then encoded in utf-8. So, how do I use Gson+Retrofit to decode it?