# Can I convert a string from hex to ascii without touching the non-hex code

Tags: java, hex

I am supposed to get **: Relevance** in a request as a parameter but I am getting **& #x3a;** Relevance. Instead of a colon(:) I am getting hex code of which is &#x3a ;

Here this Relevance is a varying parameter. So now how can I convert only hex code in a string to its ASCII and leave the other characters as is?

We use java.

Comment: `String s = yourString.replace("& #x3a;", ":")`?

Comment: Are you _really_ getting `& #x3a;`, i.e. with the space in between? Basically that "hex code" is called a html entity so what you want is to convert those to characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java

Comment: @Pavan yvs Can't you substring the string and `& #x3a;` replaced with `:` ?

Comment: @Ros5292 Thought of replacing it with : but the thing is somewhere in the application we may be getting characters other than :. So it will be better if we can be able to replace only the hexcode. I wonder if that is possible.

Comment: ya @Thomas, it is without space. but if i type &#x3a; while posting the question it is automatically converted to : . Hence I posted it that way.

Comment: Well, you could use the inline code tags (code between 2 ticks: ` code ` - just without leading or trailing whitespace :) ), e.g. `&#x3a;` :)

Comment: Have a look at the link I've posted. That question should cover your needs.