# JavaFx client recieves displays "Hello" as `&quot;Hello&quot;`

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-services, javafx

JavaFx client recieves displays "Hello" as `&quot;Hello&quot;` when response received from the API. 
The value "Hello" is set over a web-client, which is to be received over JavaFx client on making a webservice call from the JavaFx client.
Using SOAP API.

What could I be missing out on ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/how-to-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/how-to-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java)