# Decode Unicode hex characters to its string representation

Tags: java, unicode, decode

I have a record `SAMPLEID`  (with a tab character at the end) in my mySQL database (5.7.30). When fetching it from DB, I get `SAMPLEID&#x9;` instead of the original value in the record.

I googled `&#x9;` string and got to know that it represents a Unicode Hex Character Code representation of a `Tab`.

I tried decoding this string using `URLDecoder` java class's `decode` method. Passing in *UTF-8*, as encoding. Out of desperation, I tried multiple encoding *US-ASCII*, *ISO-8859-1*, *UTF-8*, *UTF-16BE*, *UTF-16LE*, *UTF-16*.

I also searched for in SO, but didn't found any relevant answer.

But none of them worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not URL-encoded, so `URLDecoder` is not useful. It also has nothing to do with character encodings, so trying different character encodings does not make any difference. It seems to be an HTML entity. See [How to unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/how-to-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java)

Comment: @Jesper That did the job. I was misdirected by the google search I guess.