# Replace ASCII codes and HTML tags in Java

Tags: java, html, string, replace, ascii

How can i achieve below expecting results without using `StringEscapeUtils` ?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String str = "<p><b>Send FWB <br><br> &#40;if AWB has COU SHC, <br> if ticked , will send FWB&#41;</b></p>";
      str = str.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
      System.out.println("After removing HTML Tags: " + str);
    }
}
```

**Current Results:**

```
After removing HTML Tags: Send FWB  &#40;if AWB has COU SHC,  if ticked , will send FWB&#41;
```

**Expecting Results:**

```
After removing HTML Tags: Send FWB  if AWB has COU SHC,  if ticked , will send FWB;
```

Already checked:
[How to unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/how-to-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java)

---

**PS:** This is just a sample example, input may vary.

Comment: your regexp is for hml tags <something> byt the html entities will match something like `&.*;` which you are not replacing

Comment: try `str = str.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>|&.*;", "");`

Comment: Above returning only `After removing HTML Tags: Send FWB `

Comment: i was wrong: `str = str.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>|&.*?;", "");` should work. tested it on https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp is for html tags `<something>` would be matched byt the html entities will not be matched. Their pattern is  something like `&.*?;` Which you are not replacing.

this should solve your trouble:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>|&.*?;", "");
```

If you want to experiment with this in a sandbox, try regxr.com and use `(\<.*?\>)|(&.*?;)` the brackets make the two different capturing groups easy to identify on the tool and are not needed in your code. note that the `\`does not need to be escaped on that sandbox playground, but it has to be in your code, since it's in a string.