# How to unescape HTML 5 entities in Java (&apos;)

Tags: java, html, apache-commons, html-entities

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/how-to-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java) mostly suggest to use apache-common-text `StringEscapeUtils`. But this (latest version of commons-text is 1.9) only supports HTML 4, and [Mastodon appears to use HTML 5](https://github.com/tootsuite/documentation/issues/884#issuecomment-864583735) which includes `&apos;`. How can I decode HTML 5 entities, including `&apos;`?

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but have you tried the *other* suggestions that are given in other answers?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca well, I would like to use a fairly standard library, and/or standard Java API _if there is any_. I also wonder why Apache doesn't support HTML 5 entities, or if I'm just missing a newer version of the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[unbescape](https://www.unbescape.org/index.html) does the job well:

```
final String unescapedText = HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml("&apos;");
System.out.println(unescapedText);
```

Result:

```
'
```

---

Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.unbescape/unbescape -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.unbescape</groupId>
    <artifactId>unbescape</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```