# Unable to decode Java UTF8

Tags: java, utf-8, decode, encode

My input for a Java program is the charcode for 年 ネン  Japanese string. I need to convert it back to Japanese.
I tried getBytes(UTF8) but couldnt succeed to convert it back to Japanese. Can you please help

I tried getBytes(UTF8).

My input is `&#24180; &#12493;&#12531;` which corresponds to the Japanese characters "年 ネン".

Comment: My input is    &#24180; &#12493;&#12531;

Comment: There are many steps involved before you can see the expected results, and each of it can play a role with your problem. Please, show us a small, complete code example, something we can compile and run on our computers. Also, do you run in an IDE, in a Windows CMD window or where? This is also quite important.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I unescape HTML character entities in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/how-can-i-unescape-html-character-entities-in-java)

Comment: You've tried what, so far?

Comment: @Josefz Your proposed duplicate is for character entities (as explicitly stated in its title), but this question is about unescaping numeric entities.

Answer (score 1):

As @skomisa has said, it's probably better to use a proper library for this, but if you want something quick-and-dirty, then:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DecimalEntityDecoder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String decimalEntities = args[0];
            String output = Arrays.stream(decimalEntities.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split(";")).
                map(s ->s.replaceAll("\\D", "")).
                mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).
                collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).
                toString();
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works fine, and I'm now thinking your quick-and-dirty approach is probably better than using a library. The sample data in the OP was clean, but it's nice to be in complete control of the process if there are issues with the input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any JDK method to resolve your issue, but you can do it in one line using Apache's [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4​()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)) method, and the code is trivial. Here's an example using your sample data:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "&#24180; &#12493;&#12531;";
        System.out.println("input=[" + input + "]");
        String output = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(input);
        System.out.println("output=[" + output + "]");
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
input=[&#24180; &#12493;&#12531;]
output=[年 ネン]
```

I ran the code using JDK 20 in Intellij IDEA.

An alternative pure Java approach would be to write the code yourself (but why bother?):

- Use a [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to extract each numeric code point from the input.
- Convert each extracted code point to a character using [Character.toString(int codePoint)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)).

Notes:

- The javadoc for `unescapeHtml4()` does not explicitly state that it supports numeric entities in the format you specify them, but it seems to work fine.
- The `StringEscapeUtils` class can be found in both `org.apache.commons.text` and `org.apache.commons.lang`. Be sure to use the `org.apache.commons.text` implementation.
- You will need to download the [Apache Commons Text library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) and add it to your project, and import `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;` in your code.
- You will also need to download the [Apache Commons Lang library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and add it to your project. Otherwise you will get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.Range` at runtime.
- Any spaces in the input will be preserved by `unescapeHtml4()` in the output.